# Reliable way to make a delay in Python3 code

Tags: windows, python-3.x, tkinter, delay

I have a python 3 program and need a delay of 20 Seconds I have tried time.sleep(20) but that causes loads of problems like program stop responding on windows by the way I'm using tkinter, does any one no a alternative way of making a delay or sample code is there a way I can do this with loop?

Comment: *like program stop responding on windows*: that is not  a problem but the *natural* behavior

Comment: alternative way to make delay?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167334/alternative-to-pythons-time-sleep

Comment: very good! thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167334/alternative-to-pythons-time-sleep

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter provides a way to schedule a function to run in the future with the universal method `after`. For example, to call `do_something` in 20 seconds you would do it like this:

```
root = tk.Tk()
...
root.after(20000, do_something)
```

Comment: That is more effective and appropriate when working with Tkinter than what is mentioned in the link I gave him.

Comment: That good if your working with tkinter elements, but in my case I was working with functions

Comment: @JJLongOne: your post specifically mentions tkinter.

Comment: @JJLongOne, don't sleep, wait or do CPU-intensive processing in the main thread. It needs to be responsive to handle its event loop and interface to the platform's window manager. Functions such as `after` allow cooperating with the toolkit's event loop. It's not just for working with Tk elements.

Comment: @JJLongOne To be super clear, `do_something` in the .after call can be *any* function.  tk does not know or care what `do_something` does.  It just calls it.  The one constraint is that `do_something` should execute quickly, so that tk can attend to other events.  If necessary, `do_something` should do just part of its work and then schedule itself to be called again.  Searching SO for `[tkinter] root.after` will lead you to many examples.