# How do I make a timer in python?

Tags: python, timer, sleep

I want a timer, but I want it to just affect one function, so it can't just be 
`sleep()`.

For example:

```
def printSomething():
    print("Something")
def functionWithTheTimer():
    for i in range(0, 5):
        #wait for 1 second
        print("Timer ran out")
```

Say the first function is called when a button is clicked, and the second function should print something out every second, both should act independently.

If I used `sleep()`, I couldn't execute the first function within that one second, and that's a problem for me. How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run certain code every n seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393612/run-certain-code-every-n-seconds)

Comment: This could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167334/alternative-to-pythons-time-sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your timer function, you may want to do something like this:

```
def functionWithTheTimer():
    for i in reversed(range(1, 6)):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    print("finished")
```

This will print the range backwards (like a countdown), one number every second.

**EDIT**: To run a function during that time, you can just duplicate and shorten the wait time. Example:

```
def functionWithTheTimer():
    for i in reversed(range(1, 6)):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        YourFunctionHere()
        time.sleep(0.5)
    print("finished")
```

You can play with the timings a little so you can get your appropriate output.

Comment: He said do not use sleep()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datetime library like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def functionwithtimer():
   start_time = datetime.now()
   # code stuff you have here 
   print("This function took: ", datetime.now() - start_time)
```